# after importing: Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: xxx\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

Tags: java, android

I imported a ready sample project from the web (an Ad company).
I am having errors on this project "Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: xxx\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist"

I saw the answers to Similar Questions that mainly say:
a- Check if you have the most up to date android tools (I have)
b- Clean the project (doesn't help)
c- Close and re-open Project (doesn't help)

I will be very grateful for any path to solve this except three options I brought.